# Node async loop - how to make this code run in sequential order?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I know there are several posts about this, but according to those I've found, this should work correctly.

I want to make an http request in a loop and I do not want the loop to iterate until the request callback has been fired. I'm using the async library like so:

```
const async = require("async");
const request = require("request");

let data = [
    "Larry",
    "Curly",
    "Moe"
];

async.forEachOf(data, (result, idx, callback) => {
    console.log("Loop iterated", idx);
    let fullUri = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
    request({
        url: fullUri
    }, 
    (err, res, body) => {
        console.log("Request callback fired...");
        if (err || res.statusCode !== 200) return callback(err);
        console.log(result);
        callback();
    });
});
```

What I see is:

```
Loop iterated 0
Loop iterated 1
Loop iterated 2
Request callback fired...
Curly
Request callback fired...
Larry
Request callback fired...
Moe
```

What I need to see is:

```
Loop iterated 0
Request callback fired...
Curly
Loop iterated 1
Request callback fired...
Larry
Loop iterated 2
Request callback fired...
Moe
```

Also, if there's a built-in way to do the same thing (async/await? Promise?) and the async library could be removed, that'd be even better.

I've seen some examples of recursion out there that are clever, but when I put this to use in a much more complex situation (e.g. multiple request calls per-loop, etc.) I feel like that approach is hard to follow, and isn't as readable.

Comment: Don't you mean 'eachOfSeries'?  forEachOf (eachOf) is parallel.

Comment: @JimBaldwin - Excellent, thanks! I missed that one. This works, but will now be looking at a way to do it w/o async.

Comment: Reminder that [`request` is deprecated](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142).

Answer (score 8):

You can ditch `async` altogether and go for `async/await` quite easily.

### Promisify your request and use `async/await`

Just turn `request` into a `Promise` so you can `await` on it.

Better yet just use [request-promise-native](https://github.com/request/request-promise-native) that already wraps request using native Promises.

#### Serial example

From then on it's a slam dunk with `async/await`:

```
const rp = require('request-promise-native')

const users = [1, 2, 3, 4]
const results = []

for (const idUser of users) {
  const result = await rp('http://foo.com/users/' + idUser)

  results.push(result)
}
```

#### Parallel example

Now, the problem with the above solution is that it's slow - the requests run serially. That's not ideal most of the time.

If you don't need the result of the previous request for the next request, just go ahead and do a `Promise.all` to fire *parallel* requests.

```
const users = [1, 2, 3, 4]

const pendingPromises = []
for (const idUser of users) {
  // Here we won't `await` on *each and every* request.
  // We'll just prepare it and push it into an Array
  pendingPromises.push(rp('http://foo.com/users/' + idUser))
}

// Then we `await` on a a `Promise.all` of those requests
// which will fire all the prepared promises *simultaneously*, 
// and resolve when all have been completed
const results = await Promise.all(pendingPromises)
```

#### Error handling

Error handling in `async/await` is provided by plain-old `try..catch` blocks, which I've omitted for brevity.

Comment: Thanks, Nicholas. Tried tagging you and can't. This routine will be part of a very large CSV upload. How many pending promises is too many? What if I have 100,000 records? Or...millions?

Comment: Uh oh - You might run into call stack limit issues with that many functions being created - the same problem would be exhibited with your callback-style code though. Also what about memory? Do you intend to load the entire CSV in-memory? Does it fit? You might need to look into [streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html). What exactly do you need to do?

Comment: I figured as much. Testing with small files now but anticipate much larger. I'm already streaming the file into an API endpoint via multer. I then need to process each row, split it into several records, which are then inserted into tables scattered across a few other microservice endpoints...hence the "request" calls.

Comment: Ok great. Can you open another question for this so I can help you out there?

Comment: Done. Many thanks! It can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999919/node-microservices-processing-large-csv-uploads

Answer (score 0):

If you have many (thousands) of urls to process it's best to define a batch size and recursively call the process function to process one batch.

It's also best to limit amount of active connections, you can use [this](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/lib/blob/master/src/index.js) to throttle active connections or connections within a certain time (only 5 per second).

Last but not least; if you use `Promise.all` you want to make sure not all successes are lost when one promise rejects. You can catch rejected requests and return a `Fail` type object so it'll then resolve with this Fail type.

The code would look something like this:

```
const async = require("async");
//lib comes from: https://github.com/amsterdamharu/lib/blob/master/src/index.js
const lib = require("lib");
const request = require("request");

const Fail = function(reason){this.reason=reason;};
const isFail = o=>(o&&o.constructor)===Fail;
const requestAsPromise = fullUri =>
  new Promise(
    (resolve,reject)=>
      request({
        url: fullUri
      }, 
      (err, res, body) => {
        console.log("Request callback fired...");
        if (err || res.statusCode !== 200) reject(err);
        console.log("Success:",fullUri);
        resolve([res,body]);
      })
  )
const process = 
  handleBatchResult =>
  batchSize =>
  maxFunction =>
  urls =>
    Promise.all(
      urls.slice(0,batchSize)
      .map(
        url=>
          maxFunction(requestAsPromise)(url)
          .catch(err=>new Fail([err,url]))//catch reject and resolve with fail object
      )
    )
    .then(handleBatch)
    .catch(panic=>console.error(panic))
    .then(//recursively call itself with next batch
      _=>
        process(handleBatchResult)(batchSize)(maxFunction)(urls.slice(batchSize))
    );

const handleBatch = results =>{//this will handle results of a batch
  //maybe write successes to file but certainly write failed
  //  you can retry later     
  const successes = results.filter(result=>!isFail(result));
  //failed are the requests that failed
  const failed = results.filter(isFail);
  //To get the failed urls you can do
  const failedUrls = failed.map(([error,url])=>url);
};

const per_batch_1000_max_10_active = 
  process (handleBatch) (1000) (lib.throttle(10));

//start the process
per_batch_1000_max_10_active(largeArrayOfUrls)
.then(
  result=>console.log("Process done")
  ,err=>console.error("This should not happen:".err)
);
```

In your `handleBatchResult` you can store failed requests to a file to try later `const [error,uri] = failedResultItem;` you should give up if a high amount of requests are failing.

After `handleBatchResult` there is a `.catch`, that is your panic mode, it should not fail there so I'd advice to [pipe errors to a file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/625224/how-to-redirect-stderr-to-a-file) (linux).