# How to throttle typescript functions that return output

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, throttling, delayed-execution

I am writing a node.js application using typescript. My application will have several services communicating with each other. Several of the services need to call an external API. This API has a restriction on the number of calls per second that can be executed. Because of this I want to create one service that wraps the external API calls (let's call it ApiService). The other services will call this one and it will collect their requests in a queue and execute them sequentially - N requests per second (for simplicity let's assume 1 per second). When service A calls a method of the ApiService - it expects to receive an output (it is fine to receive a Promise).

Now my question is - how to queue these API calls in the ApiService, so that every 1 second the next call in the queue is executed and also return the output of that API call to the caller of the ApiService?

Here's a sample service:

```
export class ServiceA {
   apiService: ApiService;

   public constructor(_apiService: ApiService) {
      apiService = _apiService;
   }

   public async DoWork() {
      // Do some stuff
      const output: number = await apiService.RetrieveA(param1, param2);
      // Do something with the output
   }
}
```

The ApiService:

```
export class ApiService {
   queue: (() => Promise<any>)[] = [];

   public async RetrieveA(param1, param2): Promise<number> {
      const func = async () => {
         return this.CallApi(param1, param2);
      };

      this.queue.push(func);
      return func();
   }

   public async RunQueue() {
      while(true) {
         const func = this.queue.shift();
         if (!func) { continue; }
         // Call the function after 1 second
         await setTimeout(() => { func(); }, 1000);
      }
   }

   private async CallApi(param1, param2): Promise<number> {
      // Call the external API, process its output and return
   }
}
```

The main method that orchestrates the whole thing:

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;

const apiService = new ApiService();
const service = new ServiceA(apiService);

new CronJob('* * * * * *', function() {
   service.DoWork();
}, null, true);

apiService.RunQueue();
```

The problem I am facing is that when RetrieveA method returns func() - the function gets executed. I need to return a Promise but the actual function execution needs to happen in RunQueue() method. Is there a way to achieve this? Can I return a promise without executing the function right away and upon awaiting this promise - to receive the output when the function is called in the RunQueue method?

Or is there a different approach to solving my issue of throttling API calls that return output?

I am new to the Node.js/Typescript/JavaScript world, so any help is appreciated :)

Comment: If you have a lot of items to async results then maybe the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48001650/1641941) can help. You can throttle active promises or amount of promises per period (like no more than 10 per second). If you really have a lot of data to process that code shows you you chunk it up to 1000 per batch. You can use a [stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47999961/1641941) as the source of the data, batch it up to say 1000 per batch and throttle the amount of active promises.

Comment: Not sure I quite understand your suggestion. I don't see how can I return the Promise to the caller of my ApiService, yet execute the method that calculates it at an arbitrary point in time. Also I don't have a lot of items, for example about 30 every 10 seconds, what's important for me is that I don't execute more than 2 per second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of that could be a lot simpler if you want to restrict calls to RetreiveA to 2 per second:

```
//lib is here: https://github.com/amsterdamharu/lib/blob/master/src/index.js
import * as lib from '../../src/index'
const twoPerSecond = lib.throttlePeriod(2,1000);
export class ApiService {
  public RetrieveA(param1, param2): Promise<number> {
    //removed the resolver part, according to the typescript signature
    //  it should return a promise of number but resolver actually takes
    //  that number and returns void (undefined?)
    return twoPerSecond(this.CallApi.bind(this))([param1, param2]);
  }
  //change the signature of this function to take one parameter
  //  but deconsruct the array to param1 and param2
  private async CallApi([param1, param2]): Promise<number> {
    // Call the external API, process its output and return
  }
}
```

Your method only works if there is only ever one instance of this class. If you were to create multiple instances and call `RetrieveA` on those instances you no longer limit requests to `callApi`.

Comment: That's true, but I do intend to have just a single instance of this class (and pass it as parameter to every other service that will use it) :) Your suggestion will work, but it seem only if I have a single RetrieveA method. However I need to have multiple methods (e.g. RetrieveB, RetrieveC...) - all of these methods will call different methods of the external API. But the restriction I have is no more than 2 API calls per second (regardless of what the API calls are). So I need to sync the calls to all methods, not just a single one.

Comment: @dbarfonchovski You can get rid of the queue and all that by not directly calling the api: `someApi(param1,param2)` but instead use the `twoPerSecond`: `twoPerSecond(someApi)([param1,param2])` That requires your api function signature to change to receive one array (tuple in C#) and deconstruct it. Or you can call the api like so: `twoPerSecond(([param1,param2])=>someApi(param1,param2))([param1,param2])` Since you're using classes and probably `this` you'll  soon find that that is a horrible way of doing things: https://youtu.be/DePE0ffiMf4?t=44m40s

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but I still can't understand how to throttle calls to multiple API methods. Maybe I'm missing your point, or I haven't explained my problem well enough. Imagine the external API has 3 methods - `GetA`, `GetB` and `GetC`. Using `twoPerSecond` I will be able to limit the calls to `GetA` to 2 per second. However during that 1 second - I don't want calls to `GetB` and `GetC` to be executed. The API restriction is 2 calls per second, regardless of the API method. So if in 1 second I send 2 calls to `GetA` and 1 to `GetB` - that will cause an error.

Comment: @dbarfonchovski There is only one `twoPerSecond` function, no matter what other function you pass to the `twoPerSecond` it'll only start 2 per second. So you can do: `twoPerSecond(this.GetA.bind(this)([param1,param2])` then `twoPerSecond(this.GetB.bind(this)([param1,param2])` then `twoPerSecond(this.GetC.bind(this)([param1,param2])`. The first second GetA and GetB will be started and the next second GetC will be started.

Comment: @dbarfonchovski The twoPerSecond function contains the logic you now spread out over every method and your class. The [comment](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/lib/blob/master/src/index.js#L270-L286) on the function says that the function passed to this function will not be called if more than max within period were already called, the example shows the same function but it really doesn't matter what function you pass (as long as it returns a promise).

Comment: Ok, I think I understand you now. The single instance of `twoPerSecond` is what's synchronizing the calls to the different API methods. Is there by any chance an NPM package with this functionality?

Comment: @dbarfonchovski Not that I know of. The function is not that big. You can put it in your own library file.

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to find a working solution. I'm not very familiar with the whole Promise and async concept in JavaScript, so this may not be the best solution, but it does the job for my specific case. Here is the code for anyone else looking to implement something similar:

The sample ServiceA remains the same as above:

```
export class ServiceA {
   apiService: ApiService;

   public constructor(_apiService: ApiService) {
      apiService = _apiService;
   }

   public async DoWork() {
      // Do some stuff
      const output: number = await apiService.RetrieveA(param1, param2);
      // Do something with the output
   }
}
```

Here's the modified ApiService that returns promises for the output and throttles the actual function execution:

```
export class ApiService {
   // We keep the functions that need to be executed in this queue
   // and process them sequentially
   queue: (() => void)[] = [];

   public async RetrieveA(param1, param2): Promise<number> {
      // This resolver serves two purposes - it will be called when the
      // function is executed (to set the output), but will also be part
      // of the Promise that will be returned to the caller (so that the
      // caller can await for the result).
      let resolver: (value: number) => void;

      // This function will be executed by the RunQueue method when its
      // turn has come. It makes a call to the external API and when that
      // call succeeds - the resolver is called to return the result through
      // the Promise.
      const func = async () => {
         return this.CallApi(param1, param2).then(resolver);
      };

      this.queue.push(func);

      // This is the promise that we return to the caller, so that he
      // can await for the result. 
      const promise = new Promise<number>((resolve, reject) => {
         resolver = resolve;
      });

      return promise;
   }

   public async Run() {
      this.RunQueue(this.queue);
   }

   private async RunQueue(funcQueue: (() => void)[]) {
      // Get the first element of the queue
      const func = funcQueue.shift();

      // If the queue is empty - this method will continue to run
      // until a new element is added to the queue
      if (func) {
         await func();
      }

      // Recursively call the function again after 1 second
      // This will process the next element in the queue
      setTimeout(() => {
         this.RunQueue(funcQueue);
      }, 1000);
   }

   private async CallApi(param1, param2): Promise<number> {
      // Call the external API, process its output and return
   }
}
```

I hope the comments in the code make it clear what (and how) I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I feel like I comment this everywhere, but I prefer `const delay = time => new Promise(res=>setTimeout(res,time))`  then use `await delay(1000)` :)

Comment: This looks better than what I had :) Thanks for the suggestion, I will use it in my code. Still learning :)

Comment: Ha, you seem like you are doing pretty well. I like the layout. :) (What language are you coming from?)

Comment: 10 years of C# development. It was about time I switched to more modern technologies. Still finding it hard to get used to, but learning new things is always fun.