# Using Promise.all() to fetch a list of urls with await statements

Tags: javascript

**tl;dr** - if you have to filter the promises (say for errored ones) don't use async functions

I'm trying to fetch a list of urls with async and parse them, the problem is that if there's an error with one of the urls when I'm fetching - let's say for some reason the api endpoint doesn't exists - the program crushes on the parsing with the obvious error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: ext is not iterable
```

I've tried checking if the res.json() is undefined, but obviously that's not it as it complains about the entire 'ext' array of promises not being iterable.

```
async function fetchAll() {
  let data
  let ext
  try {
    data = await Promise.all(urls.map(url=>fetch(url)))
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
  try {
    ext = await Promise.all(data.map(res => {
      if (res.json()==! 'undefined') { return res.json()}
    }))
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
  for (let item of ext) {
    console.log(ext)
  }
}
```

Question 1:

How do I fix the above so it won't crash on an invalid address?

Question 2:

My next step is to write the extracted data to the database.
Assuming the data size of 2-5mgb of content, is my approach of using Promise.all() memory efficient? Or will it be more memory efficient and otherwise to write a for loop which handles each fetch then on the same iteration writes to the database and only then handles the next fetch?

Comment: Your error is happening in the for loop

Comment: Clarification: you have `if (res.json()==! 'undefined')` which is not the same as `!== undefined`. Was this intentional?

Comment: `if (res.json()==! 'undefined')` makes no sense. Also you cannot call `.json()` twice on the same response

Comment: I've editted my suggestion, where I suggest you call `res.json` in your own fetch function

Comment: Yeah it just hit me, as well. How silly thanks

Comment: Clarification: You have `for (let item of ext)` in a spot where ext might be undefined. Is this intentional?

Comment: the string around undefined is a mistake

Comment: Your error is in the for loop. I'm guessing you're getting an error and ext is undefined, which calling for on will blow up

Comment: No and I think that's the problem

Comment: I agreed there. I'm stating that the problem is you're catching an error at the assignment of `ext` and not assigning anything to `ext` and then calling for on `ext`

Comment: Where will you put the clause: if (result.json) return await result.json()? If it was promises with .thens it's easy to just stick it on a .then() and create a new array, but with promise.All the array is created for me?

Comment: @S.Schenk number 2 is really a seperate step that should be done AFTER the fetch of the URLS and in a seperate function that takes the return of the first function. You could easily chain that with a .then in the calling context.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have several problems with your code on a fundamental basis. We should address those in order and the first is that you're not passing in any URLS!

```
async function fetchAll(urls) {
  let data
  let ext
  try {
    data = await Promise.all(urls.map(url=>fetch(url)))
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
  try {
    ext = await Promise.all(data.map(res => {
      if (res.json()==! 'undefined') { return res.json()}
    }))
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
  for (let item of ext) {
    console.log(ext)
  }
}
```

First you have several try catch blocks on DEPENDANT DATA. They should all be in a single try catch block:

```
async function fetchAll(urls) {
  try {
    let data = await Promise.all(urls.map(url=>fetch(url)))
    let ext = await Promise.all(data.map(res => {
      // also fixed the ==! 'undefined'
      if (res.json() !== undefined) { return res.json()}
    }))
    for (let item of ext) {
      console.log(ext)
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

Next is the problem that res.json() returns a promise wrapped around an object if it exists

```
if (res.json() !== undefined) { return res.json()}
```

This is not how you should be using the .json() method. It will fail if there is no parsable json. You should be putting a .catch on it

```
async function fetchAll(urls) {
  try {
    let data = await Promise.all(urls.map(url => fetch(url).catch(err => err)))
    let ext = await Promise.all(data.map(res => res.json ? res.json().catch(err => err) : res))
    for (let item of ext) {
      console.log(ext)
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

Now when it cannot fetch a URL, or parse a JSON you'll get the error and it will cascade down without throwing. Now your try catch block will ONLY throw if there is a different error that happens.

Of course this means we're putting an error handler on each promise and cascading the error, but that's not exactly a bad thing as it allows ALL of the fetches to happen and for you to distinguish which fetches failed. Which is a lot better than just having a generic handler for all fetches and not knowing which one failed.

But now we have it in a form where we can see that there is some better optimizations that can be performed to the code

```
async function fetchAll(urls) {
  try {
    let ext = await Promise.all(
      urls.map(url => fetch(url)
        .then(r => r.json())
        .catch(error => ({ error, url }))
      )
    )
    for (let item of ext) {
      console.log(ext)
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

Now with a much smaller footprint, better error handling, and readable, maintainable code, we can decide what we eventually want to return. Now the function can live wherever, be reused, and all it takes is a single array of simple GET URLs.

Next step is to do something with them so we probably want to return the array, which will be wrapped in a promise, and realistically we want the error to bubble since we've handled each fetch error, so we should also remove the try catch. At that point making it async no longer helps, and actively harms. Eventually we get a small function that groups all URL resolutions, or errors with their respective URL that we can easily filter over, map over, and chain!

```
function fetchAll(urls) {
  return Promise.all(
    urls.map(url => fetch(url)
      .then(r => r.json())
      .then(data => ({ data, url }))
      .catch(error => ({ error, url }))
    )
  )
}
```

Now we get back an array of similar objects, each with the url it fetched, and either data or an error field! This makes chaining and inspecting SUPER easy.

Comment: Would it not be much simpler to do: `urls.map(fetch).then(r=>r.json()).catch(error=>new Fail([error,url])` You get an array of objects and can pick out the Failed items more easily with information about the error and the url.

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to address each fundemental flaw. Something came up at work before I was able to post that EXACT line of code believe it or not...

Comment: I believe, been there.

Comment: Whoops forgot to hav closure to the individual URL

Comment: Yeah my code was indeed very messy from trying different things, I should have fixed it before posting and maybe included the makeUrls function as well. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: The good news is that now you can easily chain this function in your code. Good luck storing to the DB! And don't forget to modify with what you want to return! Here you should group the errors and use the calling context to filter them out, so probably you just want to return

Comment: @S.Schenk updated with a final version since we've solved the need for async await(which more often that not, is unneeded)

Comment: Amazing all of that and it brought me back to using just promises which was what I was using to begin with. I'm starting to wonder if I should drop the async functions I wrote for the db write and just go with promises as well.

Comment: You'd be surprised how RARELY I use generators, adapters, or async await...

Comment: Also with database transactions an array is more than helpful since you can translate them into relevant data types and then generate a single multi row insert which is a great feature of SQL, which means you don't need a transaction or multiple insert, just a single... albeit HUGE query. But that's a separate subject and separate question entirely

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169695/discussion-between-robert-mennell-and-s-schenk).

Answer (score 4):

You are getting a `TypeError: ext is not iterable` - because `ext` is still `undefined` when you caught an error and did not assign an array to it. Trying to loop over it will then throw an exception that you do not catch.

I guess you're looking for

```
async function fetchAll() {
  try {
    const data = await Promise.all(urls.map(url => fetch(url)));
    const ext = await Promise.all(data.map(res => res.json()));
    for (let item of ext) {
      console.log(item);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: This was pretty close to what my eventual code came out to as well, but you're missing something: If any individual promise errors, they will now all error and they will not know which one did. By instead handling the errors in place, we can instead allow cascading for better handling in the long run

Comment: @RobertMennell I would expect the error message to contain the url of the failed request. If it doesn't, sure we can add them, but I tried to address the fundamental problem only.

Comment: Fair and I did misspeak. They won't all error, but they will all reject

Comment: Also it would depend on the step it rejects at... Man I hate Async functions... Where is my error bubbling?

Comment: @RobertMennell Errors bubble just like in normal functions, as if `await` was a `throw`.

Comment: I know, but inside the promise.all I meant at which index of the map. It was an attempt at humor and how confusing async await with Promise.all gets

Comment: This is what I used. It is concise and feels synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `fetch(url)` on line 5, make your own function, `customFetch`, which calls fetch but maybe returns null, or an error object, instead of throwing.

something like

```
async customFetch(url) {
    try {
       let result = await fetch(url);
       if (result.json) return await result.json();
    }
    catch(e) {return e}
}
```

Comment: Fetch returns a promise, awaiting a fetch is fine especially for simple GETs, and especially if you want it to fail if any of them fail

Comment: I was suggesting this because I thought his problem was that fetch was throwing an error

Comment: It's not. The problem is in his for loop. He shouldn't be using a for loop unless he knows it's an iterable.

Comment: Ontop of that he has basic coding errors that are leading to this situation

Comment: No the problem is that it can use map if there's an invalid url, but I don't know how to handle it with Promise.all

Comment: `Promise.all` errors whenever one of the internal promises errors, so whatever advice anyone gives you here, it will boil down to -- Make sure that you wrap the promises in an error handler before passing them to Promise.all

Comment: Figure out which function specifically is erroring (I'm guessing it's res.json()) and wrap it in a try-catch to swallow the error. You can resolve with an error rather than reject with an error.

Comment: This example is a mutation of async handling and promises that can actually lead to more user error. We can save dozens of characters by just adding a `.catch(err => err)` to each fetch and allowing us to have a more compact and readable footprint since this is the code area that would ACTUALLY be where you want to handle the error

Comment: @Rober Mennel It works but I see your point. Basically I'm looking for a way to do if (result.json) return await result.json() where is the best place to execute the clause?

Comment: @S.Schenk you don't. That's an anti pattern. You're no longer in an async function inside of `Array.map`

Comment: So how can I filter the responses that don't yield a json  but an error object?

Comment: Array.filter is pretty helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 0):

`if (res.json()==! 'undefined')`

Makes no sense whatsoever *and* is an asynchronous function. Remove that condition and just return `res.json()`:

```
try {
    ext = await Promise.all(data.map(res => res.json()))
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
}
```

Whether or not your approach is "best" or "memory efficient" is up for debate. Ask another question for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can have `fetch` and `json` not fail by catching the error and return a special `Fail` object that you will filter out later:

```
function Fail(reason){this.reason=reason;};
const isFail = o => (o&&o.constructor)===Fail;
const isNotFail = o => !isFail(o);
const fetchAll = () =>
  Promise.all(
    urls.map(
      url=>
        fetch(url)
       .then(response=>response.json())
       .catch(error=>new Fail([url,error]))
    )
  );

//how to use:
fetchAll()
.then(
  results=>{
    const successes = results.filter(isNotFail);
    const fails = results.filter(isFail);

    fails.forEach(
      e=>console.log(`failed url:${e.reason[0]}, error:`,e.reason[1])
    )
  }
)
```

As for question 2:

Depending on how many urls you got you may want to [throttle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48001650/1641941) your requests and if the urls come from a large file (gigabytes) you can use [stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47999961/1641941) combined with the throttle.

Answer (score 0):

```
async function fetchAll(url) {
    return Promise.all(
      url.map(
        async (n) => fetch(n).then(r => r.json())
      )
    );
 }

 fetchAll([...])
   .then(d => console.log(d))
   .catch(e => console.error(e));

  Will this work for you?
```

Comment: Not sure why your map function is `async` it would return a promise anyway since `fetch` returns a promise. You're not catching the error so all urls will fail if one fails and calling fetchAll will only result in getting the one error, not all the successful ones.

Comment: AFAIK, should be no harm to put the async syntax there. It serves an indication to me that this is an asynchronous function. This applies to function as well. I could know immediately that this is async or not.

Comment: Yes but it still doesn't address the problem that the OP described. If urls has 100 values and the last one fails the function only goes into catch with the error and 99 successful requests are gone. Also the `.then` is a pretty good indication we're dealing with promises.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't depend on every resource being a success I would have gone back to basics skipping async/await

I would process each fetch individual so I could catch the error for just the one that fails

```
function fetchAll() {
  const result = []
  const que = urls.map(url => 
    fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(item => {
      result.push(item)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // could't fetch resource or the
      // response was not a json response
    })
  )

  return Promise.all(que).then(() => result)
}
```

Something good @TKoL said:

> Promise.all errors whenever one of the internal promises errors, so whatever advice anyone gives you here, it will boil down to -- Make sure that you wrap the promises in an error handler before passing them to Promise.all

Answer (score -1):

Regarding **question 1**, please refer to this:

[Handling errors in Promise.all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362733/handling-errors-in-promise-all)

> Promise.all is all or nothing. It resolves once all promises in the array resolve, or reject as soon as one of them rejects. In other words, it either resolves with an array of all resolved values, or rejects with a single error.

Comment: The error is in the for loop. He's ACTUALLY handling with the try catch in the async await. The problem is he's calling a for loop on what is possibly and undefined