# How to create an array of uncalled promise functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise

My problem is I cannot construct the promisesArray.

This works perfectly but I need to construct this array on the fly.

```
var promisesArray=[get(url1),get(url2),get(url3)];  // url1,url2,url3 are valid urls here

var promises = Promise.all(promisesArray);

promises.then(function(results) {
 console.log('this came back: ',results);
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});;

function get(url) {
  // Return a new promise.
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // Do the usual XMLHttpRequest stuff

  });
}
```

I am trying to build the array promisesArray above, where each element is a promise, but every way I try I am only adding the result of calling get()
and I end up with an array of pending promises

```
Array [ Promise { "pending" }, Promise { "pending" }, Promise { "pending" }]
```

When I want:

```
promisesArray=[get(url1),get(url2),get(url3)];
```

For example, I have tried:

```
let template=['a','b','c','d'];

  var promiseArray=[]
  template.forEach(function(pos){
      let url=lookupUrl[pos]]();  //just a function that returns a Url determined by the values of template array
          promiseArray.push(get(url));
  })
```

but obviously I am only returning the result of the get call here..

I tried using bind, but once again I end up with an array of executing promises...

```
 var promiseArray = template.map(function(pos){
   var url = lookupUrl[pos]]();
   var out= get.bind(null,url);
   return out()
 })
```

I don't know how to create an array of uncalled functions.

[EDIT_UPDATE]
As @JaromandaX pointed out in the first comment I already had what I needed, and in fact either of the above two methods work for building the array of promises. As @Roamer-1888 also pointed out, I got side tracked into thinking that I needed an array of 'uncalled functions' which was not true.

I like the method used by @HMR in his answer so I am going to try that.

Comment: so, you want an array of promises, not an array of promises?

Comment: when/how will the `get` be started? I mean, you could do `function get(url) {
    return function() {
        // Return a new promise.
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // Do the usual XMLHttpRequest stuff
        });
    };
}` ... then you have an array of functions, but how will they be called?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your question. I need the array as in the first section of code that works, where I typed into my program the array of promises.. I can't build it programatically.

Comment: so, you want your array to be an array of Promises?

Comment: I guess the Promise.all function calls them

Comment: No, Promise.all waits for their completion

Comment: @JaromandaX . Yes an array of uncalled functions that are then called by the Promise.all

Comment: Promise.all does not call functions, it waits for Promises to resolve

Comment: What problem are you having with the overall code in the first snippet? Does `console.log('this came back: ',results);` output something you didn't expect?

Comment: @JaromandaX..ok I see...obviously more here that I don't understand than I thought..

Comment: @JaromandaX.. the first code snippet works but I need to generate lots of these arrays dynamically

Comment: then do so, there's nothing wrong with that code at all

Comment: `let url=lookupUrl[pos]]();` - have you verified that this returns the expected url?

Comment: @JaromandaX.. you are right.. I get it, I didn't understand what the Promise.all was doing, I thought it was actually calling the functions. Thanks

Comment: So @JaromandaX, what I don't understand now is how were the get(url) functions inside the array called in my first snippet?..

Comment: didn't you say you had an array of promises?

Comment: yes the first line of the first snippet, but I didn't think the functions inside the array would be called just by declaring the var promisesArray

Comment: You function gets called in the Promise constructor. Its *executor*  parameter is called immediately. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise So as soon as you call (`()`) your `get` function , the `// Do the usual XMLHttpRequest stuff` will get called.

Comment: "but obviously I am only returning the result of the get call here", yes and that's precisely what you want, or at least what you initially asked for before you got side-tracked into "array of uncalled functions".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for map:

```
Promise.all(
  urls.map(get)
)
```

If you have an array of template then map those to url and then url to promise:

```
const template=['a','b','c','d'];

Promise.all(
  template.map(//map pos to url
    pos=>lookupUrl[pos]()
  ).map(//map url to promise
    get
  )
);
```

If you need to throttle it somehow then have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48001650/1641941).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you build you array of functions that return the get-promise and then defer execution until you're inside `promise.all`?

```
var promisesArray=[()=>get(url1),()=>get(url2),()=>get(url3)];

promise.all(promisesArray.map((x)=>x()))
```

This will kick-off all of your `get` requests at the same time and `all`'s promise won't resolve until they're all done.