# Running a promise.all of promise.alls

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have am making 400ish requests to a server - and putting each inside promises.

When running all 400 requests in a single promise.all - the system falls over.

I've split my requests into batches of 50 promises (and added them inside a promise.all), and added those all into another promise.all.

How can I run the promises in the batches, and wait for those to be done before moving onto the next?

```
// attach the other accounts a user has to the wrapper object
// **this is 400+ requests object, that has the requests in it**
// results are promises
const influencerAccounts = wrapper.map(p => addInfluencerAccounts(p));

// split the requests into chunks to stop the server falling over
const chunkedPromises = _.chunk(influencerAccounts, 50);

// promise.all on each chunk of promises/requests
// ????


// ...

return
```

I've tried looping over the chunked promised arrays (which is an array of promises) and Promise.all(ing) each one - but that's not going to wait from the previous batch to finish before sending the next.

Thanks,

Ollie

Comment: I guess `createInfluencerWrapper` has the fetch request in it and will make the request so when you set `wraper` you're already made all the requests. If you'd like to throttle the amount of requests then wrap the function that will return a promise in a [throttler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48001650/1641941) and maybe do not allow to have promises reject in the Promise.all(something.map so [return a fail object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47678417/1641941) (last code block) and sort out the rejected and successes after.

Comment: You might find it a lot easier to pick up the Bluebird promise library and use the `concurrency` setting with [Bluebird's `Promise.map()`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html).   That will let you easily code your 400 requests, but separately let you specify how many you want "in flight" at the same time to control memory and resource usage while processing them all.  Then you won't have to manually chunk them and it will both tell you when they're all done and keep track of all the results for you (in order).

Comment: Or, several other implementations you can copy and use [Promise.all consumes all my RAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46654265/promise-all-consumes-all-my-ram/46654592#46654592) or [How to control how many promises access network in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41028790/javascript-how-to-control-how-many-promises-access-network-in-parallel/41028877#41028877) or [Loop through an API vith variable URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48842555/loop-through-an-api-get-request-with-variable-url/48844820#48844820).

Comment: Also, [Make several requests to an api that can only handle 20 requests at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33378923/make-several-requests-to-an-api-that-can-only-handle-20-request-a-minute/33379149#33379149)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making a mistake a *lot* of people make at first: `Promise.all` doesn't *run* anything. It just waits for things that are *already running*. By the time you've broken your `influencerAccounts` array into chunks, you've probably already overloaded the server, because you're still sending it 400+ requests at the same time.

Instead, chunk the `payout` array, and then process it in chunks, something along these lines:

```
const results = [];
const promise =
    _.chunk(payout, 50).reduce(
        (p, chunk) =>
            p.then(chunkResults => {
                results.push(...chunkResults);
                return Promise.all(chunk.map(startRequest)); 
            })
        ,
        Promise.resolve([])
    )
    .then(() => results);
```

I've used `startRequest` above instead of `createInfluencerWrapper` and `addInfluencerAccounts` because it wasn't clear to me if you'd introduced one or the other in an attempt to make your chunking work. But if not, `startRequest` is simply `addInfluencerAccounts(createInfluencerWrapper(entry))`.

That starts a chunk of 50 requests, uses `Promise.all` to wait for all of them to complete, then starts the next chunk of 50 requests. The "do this then when it's done do that" part comes from the *promise `reduce`* idiom, which in its simple form looks like this:

```
someArray.reduce((p, entry) => p.then(() => doSomethingWith(entry)), Promise.resolve());
```

It starts with a resolved promise, and hooks a `then` handler on it to do the next thing, which hooks a `then` handler on *that* to do the next thing, etc.

---

If you don't like closing over `results`, we can pass it along the `reduce` chain; here's the first version above doing that:

```
const promise =
    _.chunk(payout, 50).reduce(
        ({p, results}, chunk) => ({
            p: p.then(chunkResults => {
                results.push(...chunkResults);
                return Promise.all(chunk.map(startRequest)); 
            }),
            results
        }),
        {p: Promise.resolve([]), results: []}
    )
    .then(({results}) => results);
```

Comment: It's simpler to start the reduction with `Promise.resolve([])`, thereby delivering at each iteration the `results` array *via* a promise rather than alongside a promise.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 - ***Doh!*** Thanks! That's just...so obvious in retrospect. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - thank you so much - I was under the impression that promises did nothing unless 'resolved - thanks so much for the distinction. This was incredibly helpful.

Comment: @Ollie - I'm really glad. You're not at all alone in having gotten that impression about them. :-)

Comment: What I had in mind was `return _.chunk(payout, 50).reduce((p, chunk) => {
 return p.then(results => {
  return Promise.all(chunk.map(addInfluencerAccounts))
  .then(newResults => results.concat(newResults));
 });
}, Promise.resolve([]));`.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 - That's basically the above, but creating and throwing away a bunch of temporary arrays rather than just adding to the one array.

Comment: Yes, exactly so, though `.concat()` isn't really the central theme. `.then(newResults => {
results.push(...newResults); return results; })` would be more efficient in that regard.